# How does Slick js carousel behave width custom css?

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

I've already asked 2 times the developer, posted an issue, and so on, but no answers, so I'll try here.

I'm deciding to switch from wootheme's flexslider (to me, currently still the overall best library) to **[Slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/)**. Have you ever tried it?

The thing I'm mainly interested (and this is not going to be an opinion, so I guess this question should be fine for stackoverflow), is how well it 'responds' to styles customisations.

Are its own css mandatory? Can I fully override them if needed? I mean, override without too much hassle... Flexslider for example lets you do not load its styles and to setup basic functionality with really few lines of css; again, I mean, styles to have the basic masking/changing images functions working. Then one starts styling anything else, obviously, but that's not the point here.

I think Flexslider is so simple because the really relevant styles are almost all inline-written via javascript. Is Slick the same?

Yes I know, I can try but myself, but I'd also like to hear from someone else who tested it, since I'm going to go straight into production code.

Comment: Notice: load that css file last, then it overrides

Comment: ...Very smart answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm going to answer my own question.

Short answer: yes, absolutely.

Long answer: Slick has 2 main css files: slick.css and slick-theme.css
You only need slick.css, and it's really tiny, and probably you would write almost the same rules if you would override it. slick.css only sets basic functionality and no presentation styles, so you will free of doing whatever you want to customise appearance.